# Is it possible to add a listener to individual google maps tiles?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The simplest example I can think of for creating custom maps tiles is the [Google maps base tile example.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base)

The only interesting part going on here is what we put in getTile():

```
CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
  var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = coord;
  div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
  div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
  div.style.fontSize = '10';
  div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
  div.style.backgroundColor = '#E5E3DF';
  return div;
};
```

Is it possible to get mouseover or click events for individual map tiles, for instance, doing something like this, just before returning the div?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'click', function() {
alert( ' test - called from addListener');
} );
```

I can't get the event to fire.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve in the end? Manipulation of the div or only detecting the click?

Comment: @Dr.Molle Both, but to start with, I'd like to at least figure out how to detect the click. It would be great if I could get something like an image map in the div.

Comment: A click on a tile may not be detected, because the div's that contain the tile-images are covered by the panes of the map. All you can do when you really need the tiles is to observe the click on the map and calculate based on the clicked LatLng which tile or feature would have been clicked(when it would be possible to click it). The features I would store in a FusionTable, the handling of the clicks via a FusionTableLayer would be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at overlays instead of tiles. Tiles may change coordinates when the user zooms in/out.
Try https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-simple

Comment: It's not just the coordinates that change, the actual tiles change, which is fine.

Comment: I don't want the roadmap at all, I want my own completely custom map. I have hundreds of thousands of features across the entire map, which is why I want to deal with the individual tiles.